Result from two different consumers in kafkajs
the truth is that I'm very new to this, and I'm still not sure if I'm using the correct strategy or if I'm not using kafkajs correctly. I have a producer that sends messages to a topic that is partitioned into 2, and in another part of my code, I have 2 consumers. I have this doubt: Suppose a producer sends two messages where message 1 will arrive at consumer 1 and message 2 at consumer 2, and let's say message 1 is to check if a record exists in a database and message 2 is to check something else in another table. Now, I'm interested in knowing if both records were found or exist, but since they are sent to different consumers, how would this situation be handled? (The problem is hypothetical, and assuming, for example, that these consumers help me improve the architecture's performance, I would like to know how to solve that) or when consuming the messages, should I produce to another topic where I receive both results? (In that case, how are the results now consumed?)
...
 await producer.send({
                topic: 'test-topic',
                messages: [
                 { key: 'exists-table1', value: 'some-value-1', partition: 1 }, //cosumer 1
                 { key: 'exists-table2', value: 'some-value-2', partition: 0 } //consumer 2
                ],
            });
...


Note: there's no strong guarantee a message will arrive at a specific consumer unless you manually assign partitions. But then the order of processing is still not guaranteed. If you want to guarantee order, use one partition, or you'll need some type of extra table that waits for both events

Usually all consumers of a topic will receive the messages streamed to it. So in your case both messages should be received by both listeners. It's a one to many connection. Each of your listeners could then react differently based on some logic. Good luck!

In a consumer group, each consumer does not read all messages

The two consumers I have belong to the same group, and that's why those two messages from my code go to consumers one and two. In conclusion, is it better to send both messages to the same consumer and avoid unnecessary steps?
